# Make :manpage: provide a links to webpages

Tags: python-sphinx

I am creating teaching material in Sphinx, and I often want to redirect students to a given man page. Sphinx has a nice internal syntax for this, e.g. `:manpage:ls(1)`. Unfortunately Sphinx only applies some formatting to this, resulting in a plain text output. I would like Sphinx to render a link to some web page with a given manpage, similarly as how it is done for `:rfc:` tag.

Is is doable somehow? Is there a way to easily rewrite `:manpage:` macro, so I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not find any solution so I have written a plugin that provides `:linuxman:` role and created custom links, the source is available here: https://github.com/tdi/sphinxcontrib-manpage.

Th eplugin is available on pypi, you can install it via: `pip install sphinxcontrib-manpage`.

The usage is similar to sphinx's `:manpage:` role, you just write: `:linuxman:ls(1)` and a link to http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls is generated. The url can be configured in `conf.py`.